# Can entanglement cause a chain reaction at distance after measure one particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

if we have two electrons with their spins  entangled like this:

[image: 2 entangled electrons]

And if we measure the spin on the left electron, then right electron spin also change like this:

[image: afte measure left electron s pin]

So, my question is, do this spin change on the right electron can cause a chain reaction in other particles near to it?. And what forces will be involved in that chain?.

I'm curious on why stimulus in the brain are localized when we aren't aware and propagated when we are.

Comment: I am not sure how the brain got involved at the end of the question

Comment: I have no idea what your pictures mean.  If the electrons are entangled, they don't have individual spins.

Comment: The pictures are blochs spheres from a Qiskit circuit. The first representing partial entanglement with a Von Newman entropy near 0.9. The second is after measure, so the first electron spin collide to 0 (ground energy state) and the second electron spin is changed to a superposition more near state 1 by this measure action (a microwave signal ).  So being entangled does not mean  we can not act on them individually.

Answer (score 0):

For free electrons, their spins can be aligned arbitrarily. All you need is a levitation trap and an additional magnetic field. The magnetic dipoles of two electrons can thus be placed in any relation.

However, because of their electric fields, the electrons are too far apart for their spins to interact. This is therefore not entanglement of the two electrons, I can change the spin direction of one of the two electrons without changing the spin of the second electron.

When we speak of entanglement of the spin of electrons, it is mostly in the context of their mutual influence in the atomic bond. In this, all magnetic moments of the electrons depend on each other. So if I create a chain of electron traps in a material where the magnetic dipoles of the electrons in the traps still interact, then manipulating the spin directions of one of the trapped electrons can also change the electron spins in the other traps according to the laws of entanglement.

> do this spin change on the right electron can cause a chain reaction in other particles near to it?

Only as long as the spins are entangled (via the mutual influence of the magnetic dipoles) does one spin manipulation change the spin of the other electron. Once separated, the electrons act independently.